# Multiple recaptcha v2 on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I can't make multiple recaptcha work on the same page.

**This is the main one: (login.php)**

```
                    <form method="post" id="loginForm" class="recaptcha_form">
                        <div id='message'></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>User Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="loginEmail" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style='margin-bottom:0px;'>
                        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" style='margin-bottom:1rem;'>
                            <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin pwd" required />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default reveal" tabindex="-1" type="button"><i class="fas fa-eye change-eye"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            **<div id='review_recaptcha'></div>**
                        <button id="loginSubmitButton" type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary resizeButtonBeforeLogin">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <a href="reset-password.php" class='beforeLoginLinks'>Forgot your password?</a>
                        </form>
```

**This is the second one inside the header on every page**

```
            <form method='POST' id='loginFormHeader' class='recaptcha_form'>
                                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                                            <input name='user_email' id='loginEmailHeader' placeholder='Email' class='form-control form-control-sm' type='text'
                                                            oninvalid='setCustomValidity('This is not a valid email.')' oninput='setCustomValidity('')'
                                                            pattern='^[^(\.)][a-zA-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,5}' required/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class='input-group' style='margin-bottom:1rem;'>
                                                            <input name='user_password' id='loginPasswordHeader' placeholder='Password' class='form-control form-control-sm loginPassword pwd2'
                                                            type='password' pattern='((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{6,40})'
                                                            oninvalid='setCustomValidity('This is not a valid password.')' oninput='setCustomValidity('')' required/>
                                                            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                                                                <button class='btn btn-default reveal2' tabindex='-1' type='button'><i class='fas fa-eye change-eye2'></i></button>
                                                            </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                                    **<div id='review_recaptcha2'></div>**
                                                            <button type='submit' id='loginSubmitButtonHeader' name='loginHeader' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Login</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class='form-group text-xs-center'>
                                                            <small><a href='reset-password.php'>Forgot password?</a></small>
                                                    </div>
                                            </form>
```

The weird thing is that when i am at login.php page the recaptchabox shows in the header login.

But if i am at register.php the recaptchabox in the header login doesn't show?

I don't understand.

```
var CaptchaCallback = function() {
     grecaptcha.render('review_recaptcha', {'sitekey' : 'SITE_KEY'});
     grecaptcha.render('review_recaptcha2', {'sitekey' : 'SITE_KEY'});
 };
```

I tried this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

I don't understand how if i enter the recaptcha in the login header, the recaptcha thinks i need to finish the one in the login.php page.

Can someone explain this to me?

This is the ajax file btw i use grecaptcha.reset , now it resets both of the recaptcha boxes i think.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var email = $('#loginEmail').val();
     var loginSubmit = $('#loginSubmitButton').val();
     var password = $('#loginPassword').val();
     $.ajax({
       url: "login-ajax.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { user_email:email,login:loginSubmit,user_password:password,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {

         if(data.type == 'success') {
           $('#loginSubmitButton').html(
      "<span class='spinner-border spinner-border-sm' role='status' aria-hidden='true'></span> Laden..."
        );
           window.location='products.php';
      // alert("success");
         } else if(data.type == 'error') {
           $("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-danger resizeFont' style='text-align:center;'>"+data.text+"</div>");
           $('.hideForOtherMessage').hide();
           grecaptcha.reset(review_recaptcha);
         }
       }
     });
   });
   });
```